# Empty folders named "good" appeared in some location I have been to

Tags: windows-10, security

I have just reinstalled my windows 10 due to abnormal lagging and slow reaction time. After that, empty folders named "good" started to appear in folders I have been to. Not all of them, but some. And their creation time is always before or after my arrival to that folder (e.g. When I come in and out of the target folder the first time, the "good "folder does not exist, but when I come back to the target folder again, the "good" folder is here and its time of creation is within 5 min of my first arrival to the target folder). Is this a "normal" issue, or something is wrong with my computer?

Comment: Can you clarify something? *"creation time is always before or after my arrival"* seems nearly a tautology, the only exception being that creation time is precisely the same as your arrival. Do you mean *"within 5 minutes before or after my arrival"*?

Comment: That is not normal Windows 10 behavior. It might be due to legitimate software, e.g. an antivirus tool you've installed, or it could be malware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using any CAD software?  We're experiencing something very similar here and believe it is to do with some cad software we use called "Draftsight".  We believe the "good" folder is draftsights equivalent of windows "temp" folder, but it appears to not be cleaning up after itself.

Comment: If you have any links to back up your answer, that would be great!

Comment: Sure, see here: 

https://r1132100503382-eu1-3dswym.3dexperience.3ds.com/#search:good%20folder

You may need to make an account (Free) to view their support articles.  No official word from 3ds yet, however multiple threads on the support forum for this issue.